# Ruby Sorting Array Alphabetically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, sorting, alphabetical

I have the `Array` which contains the mix data.

Its like

```
["AB_1020", "AB_950", "AB_50", "1000", "570"]
```

The output should be

```
AB_50, AB_950, AB_1020, 570, 1000
```

Comment: Don’t hesitate to go write code that performs this task.

Comment: That isn't really an alphabetical sort. Numbers usually come before characters, both in the computer world and in the paper world.

Comment: What have you tried so far and what specific problem are you facing? Do you know how to sort an array? Do you know how to sort by multiple sort keys? Do you know how to split a string? Did you manage to solve the problem by breaking it into smaller pieces (e.g. by sorting each data "type" on its own)?

Answer (score 2):

```
["AB_1020", "AB_950", "AB_50", "1000", "570"].sort_by do |k|
  i, w = k.split('_').rotate
  [w.to_s, -i.to_i]
end.reverse
#⇒ ["AB_50", "AB_950", "AB_1020", "570", "1000"]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this

```
p ["AB_1020", "AB_950", "AB_50", "1000", "570"].partition{|x| x.to_i.zero? }
      .flat_map{|x| x.sort_by {|x|x[/d+/]}.reverse}
```

ouptut

```
#⇒ ["AB_50", "AB_950", "AB_1020", "570", "1000"]
```

Comment: There's also a [`flat_map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map) method.

Comment: @SebastianPalma Ah Okay, forgotten that!

Comment: You don't take the non-numerical part (`AB`) into account when sorting, do you?

Comment: @Stefan yes, that's because the given answer by OP doesn't detail about that.